# passing multiple "on" conditions in merge_asof

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Is there any way to pass multiple `on` conditions to `merge_asof` with either similar or different tolerances?

Let's consider `df1` as:

| by1 | by2 | on1 | on2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1.1 | 1.2 |
| b | 2 | 1.3 | 1.4 |
| a | 3 | 1.5 | 1.6 |

and `df2` as:

| by1 | by2 | on1 | on2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2.1 | 2.2 |
| x | 9 | 1.3 | 1.4 |
| a | 3 | 2.5 | 6.6 |

by a tolerance of 1 for on1 and 2 for on2, I want such merge:

| by1 | by2 | on1 | on2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2.1 | 2.2 |

I have tried other methods besides merge_asof, such as nested loops, which are definitely not time efficient.
currently I'm using this code which only works for only one of my "on: conditions, in this case "on1":

```
df1= df1.sort_values(["on1"])
df2= df2.sort_values(["on1"])

df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, CaDdDfChanges, on=["on1"], by=["by1", "by2"], tolerance=ToleranceFor1, direction="nearest")
```

Comment: Will you please include your current `merge_asof` code?

Comment: done! does it help? @user17242583

Comment: Yes, that's very helpful. What's `ToleranceFor1`?